# How to generate ordered combinations of multiple sets of 2 elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I see a great deal of answers regarding finding *all* combinations or permutations of n sets, but none that fulfill the need to ensure the "order" matters (if that's the right term).

In this case, we have, say, 3 sets of 2 elements:

```
let a1 = ['b', 'z']
let a2 = ['j', 'q']
let a3 = ['i', 'y']
```

The desired combinations for the output would be all combinations containing 3 elements, with the first element coming from `a1`, the second element coming from `a2` and the third element coming from `a3`. The final output would look like the following:

```
['b', 'j', 'i']
['b', 'j', 'y']
['b', 'q', 'i']
['b', 'q', 'y']
['z', 'j', 'i']
['z', 'j', 'y']
['z', 'q', 'i']
['z', 'q', 'y']
```

Note the above does *not* include every permutation or combination...and instead enforces the rule the the first element in the result comes from one of the elements in the first array. The second element in the result comes from one of the elements in the second array. And the third element in the result comes from one of the elements in the third array.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where you struggle at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in several ways. One is to use recursion: pick the first element of the first array, and prefix it to the recursive results for the rest of the arrays. Then do the same with the second value of the first array, ...etc.

Here is that implemented with a generator:

```js
function * combis(arr, ...rest) {
    if (!arr) { // Base case: no more values to pick
        yield [];
        return;
    }
    for (let val of arr) {
        for (let result of combis(...rest)) {
            yield [val, ...result]; // Prefix value to recursive result
        }
    }
}

// Demo
let a1 = ['b', 'z'];
let a2 = ['j', 'q'];
let a3 = ['i', 'y'];

console.log(Array.from(combis(a1, a2, a3)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of recursion making use of the [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to isolate the first array on each call.

```js
const
  a1 = ['b', 'z'],
  a2 = ['j', 'q'],
  a3 = ['i', 'y'],

  combine = (arr, ...rest) => {
    return rest.length
      ? arr.flatMap(n => combine(...rest).map(m => [].concat(n, m)))
      : arr;
  },

  result = combine(a1, a2, a3);

// logging
result.forEach(r => console.log(`[${r.join(', ')}]`));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```